# How to use custom fonts with XWPFRun in apache poi api for java

Tags: android, fonts, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

**how to use custom fonts with `XWPFRun` in apache `poi` api for java**
http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html

`setFontFamily` uses system fonts how can use fonts from different location with `xwpfrun` as I am  doing project on android there are only three fonts in android I want use more fonts for word processing app.